# How to make Angular 2 Router work by rewriting the URL in deployed app?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm now finishing my Angular 2 Application and I'm wondering how to host it.

I've just tried to build the app on my localhost and actually everything seems to work fine, expect the `Router` of the app. I can't access routes by rewriting the URL because it's probably looking for some files and .htaccess RewriteRules, rather than `routes`. It's important for me to be able to access the routes by rewriting the URL, because I don't want to have `[routerLink]`s for my admin panel and some other stuff to be public (seen as a hyper-link).

To be more specific...
When I visit `http://localhost/FinalApp/` it uses router to navigate me to `http://localhost/FinalApp/list/page/1` so the `list/page/1` is add by the Angular 2 Router. All `[routerLink]`s are working correctly, and navigate me to eg. `http://localhost/FinalAll/list/category/3` when I click them, but when I'm rewriting the URL manually to get to the admin panel (I'm adding `admin` to my base `http://localhost/FinalApp/`, so the final URL looks like `http://localhost/FinalApp/admin`) it shows me 404 Error (not Router's default route, but the server-side 404).

I want to be able to manually rewrite the URL and use Angular 2 Router.

Am I missing something or is it just impossible?

Comment: You could have `<base href="/admin">` in your `index.html` so you don't need to rewrite URL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem is solved by implementing `HashLocationStrategy` which adds `#` to all your routes: `http://localhost/FinalApp/list/page/1` becomes `http://localhost/#/FinalApp/list/page/1`. You achieve this by adding `HashLocationStrategy` to `AppModule` providers:

```
{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
```

You need to import `LocationStrategy` and `HashLocationStrategy` from `@angular/common`:

```
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
```

If you are using RC4 or lower, you add this to your `bootstrap` method:

```
bootstrap(
AppComponent,
    [
        { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
    ]);
```

Comment: It's a solution, but it's possible to keep "HTML 5 URL" with some configuration in the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Great. Thank you, works perfectly. Don't you now if there is a way to hide the '#' from URL by .htaccess or something similar maybe?

Comment: @DawidZbiński To be honest, I knew there is a way do to it without adding `#`, but I never tried to do it. Maybe @NoémiSalaün can teach us something new, I would be grateful. :-)

Comment: I did not have to use pure HTML5 URL yet. Sorry. I know there is a way, but I can't say more :/

Comment: @NoémiSalaün Nevermind, I'll try to google for something. I can let you know if I find something...

Answer (score 0):

As you said, this is due to server-side routing. Using the link href, the browser is making a request to the server where you're app is hosted. If you haven't set your web server to route desired paths to your single page app, it's going to look in the system for something on the server stored at `http://localhost/FinalApp/admin`. If you use url rewriting to maintain the url in the browser, but serve the app, the app will then do all the routing once it loads. Here's a trivial and untested example:

**Example using apache rewrite**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(/.*)$ /index.html [L]
```