# Angular2 page not loading when refresh

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, load

I have problem.
When i click in my index on anchor

```
<a href ="/month/1">Month</a>
```

my app isn't loading, but meanwhile when i click on anchor in my component

```
<a routerLink="/month/1"> Month</a>
```

my app loads the page. This is my route.

```
{ path: 'month/:id', component: MonthComponent },
```

Also when page is load from the component when i refresh it, it trows the same error as when i come from the index. Before i add the parameter in the url i didn't have this problem. I tried to use routerLink in my index but it doesn't even load the url.

Comment: I wrote about that problem already, check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39649220/how-to-make-angular-2-router-work-by-rewriting-the-url-in-deployed-app/39649341#39649341

Comment: When you say "it throws the same error", do you mean it's displaying the browser 404 page, or is there an error in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is due to server-side routing. Using the link href, the browser is making a request to the server where you're app is hosted. If you haven't set your web server to route desired paths to your single page app, it's going to look in the system for something on the server stored at `where.com/month/1`

I could help with a specific example if you updated your question with your host type (eg. ExpressJS, IIS, etc.)

**Example using IIS URL Rewrite (web.config)**

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
      <rule name="Redirect To Index" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
      </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: It is on localhost:3000. I am using npm

Comment: @IoanStoianov What are you using to host it locally?

Comment: I am using npm lite-server @Fiddles

Comment: @IoanStoianov I'm at a loss, lite-server should be doing this as you expect. Have you made any bs-config overrides? Also, just to check, is your index page "index.html"?

Answer (score 0):

This due to the server being called (server-side routing).  How you solve the issue depends on how you are serving you application.  Just Html and JS (from transpiled code) then the answer above with the adjustment to the web.config will work.  If you are using MVC to serve up the application then you will need to adjust your routes to pass the request back down to the client.

.Net Core example:

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                name: "spa-fallback",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });
```